# How to include a % sign in a url?

Tags: url, encoding, query-string

Currently m trying to include % Sign In URL,m using
my Url:- We have a fairly good sized 100% remote employee group. Hopefully at these meetings with Marc and others, they are thinking about a way to deliver information to those who are remote?

Comment: Read about url encoding. Also - do you really need to show that particular message? Can't you show an anonymous example like "test%test"? And are you sure you need to do this as an URL parameter, not a POST member?

Comment: Read this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
We%20have%20a%20fairly%20good%20sized%20100%25%20remote%20employee%20group.%20Hopefully%20at%20these%20meetings%20with%20Marc%20and%20others%2C%20they%20are%20thinking%20about%20a%20way%20to%20deliver%20information%20to%20those%20who%20are%20remote%3F
```

So, it must be: `%25`